# Ruby on Rails omniauth build profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook

I am using `facebook-omniauth` to authenticate user with Facebook. Everything works fine, except how can I build user `profile` table from extra fields that I receive from omniauth.

The relationship `user` to `profile` is `has_one`, and `belongs_to` as vice versa.

Following were my `OmniauthCallbacksController`

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
    def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])


    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

In my `user.rb` model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

  has_many :products
  has_one :profile
  has_one :store_setting
  after_create :send_welcome_message
  enum status: {
    normal: 0,
    merchant: 1
  }

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)

        where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      logger.info "status=from_omniauth first_name=#{auth.info.first_name} first_last_name=#{auth.info.last_name}"
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.build_profile(auth)
        #user.name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
        #user.image = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
      end
    end



    def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
      end
    end
  end

  def build_profile(auth)
    self.Profile.new(first_name:auth.info.first_name) --> not work!!
  end

  private

  def send_welcome_message
    UserMailer.welcome_message(self).deliver

  end


end
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to override a method `buide_profile` which gives us [Active Record Methods Added by has_one](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference).

---

> **`Methods Added by has_one`**
>
> association(force_reload = false)
>
> association=(associate)
>
> build_association(attributes = {})
>
> create_association(attributes = {})
>
> create_association!(attributes = {})

---

In your case you could re-write `from_omniauth` methods

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)

    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      logger.info "status=from_omniauth first_name=#{auth.info.first_name} first_last_name=#{auth.info.last_name}"
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.build_profile(first_name: auth.info.first_name)
      #user.name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
      #user.image = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
    end
  end
```

Hope this help you!!!